# reference to android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences in xml

Tags: android

There are just two forms i knew to retrieve resource values  in xml files: '@' for drawable resources and '?' for theme resources.

Now i want to use 'android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences' for the icon used for option menu item 'settings'. But this won't work:

```
<item android:icon="@android.R.drawable/ic_menu_preferences">
```

This can be solved in code:

```
MenuItem settings;
settings.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences);
```

But from dev guide, i knew that it is better to create menu item in xml.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use

```
<item android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences">
```